# Magento Soap Api not working

Tags: magento-1.8, soap

Recently i have moved my application to dedicated server from VPS. On VPS Soap API is working good on VPS, but after moving to dedicated server its not working.

I have enabled PHP Open SSL, xmlrpc, php-soap extension, but still not working.

i have prepared a test file to test SOAP API

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set("default_socket_timeout", 6000);
        echo $host = "www.host.com/index.php"; //our online shop url
        $client = new SoapClient("http://".$host."/api/soap/?wsdl"); //soap handle
        $apiuser= "user"; //webservice user login
        $apikey = "key"; //webservice user pass
        $action = "sales_order.list"; //an action to call later (loading Sales Order List)

        try { 

          echo $sess_id= $client->login($apiuser, $apikey); //we do login

    die;

        print_r($client->call($sess_id, $action));
        }
        catch (Exception $e) { //while an error has occured
            echo "==> Error: ".$e->getMessage(); //we print this
               exit();
        }
?>
```

It give me below  error message

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://www.sanasana.com/index.php/api/soap/?wsdl' : XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document in /var/www/html/sanasoap.php:5 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/sanasoap.php(5): SoapClient->SoapClient('http://www.sana...') #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/sanasoap.php on line 5
```

I have also give full permission to /tmp folder.

```
Note: New dedicated server is a cloud server with Load balancer in front.
```

Can you one please help me out.

Thank you

Comment: I know, I know, but I'd strongly recommend to use Magento's REST API, and REST over SOAP in general.

Comment: Its 3rd party extension that uses SOAP API, so i have to make it work for that.

Answer (score 1):

Issue is resolved. On close observation, i found additional space on first line of index.php . On removing that it start working properly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you server can't resolve his own domain.
you can verify that with wget "your host" on your server

add you domain to /etc/hosts

Comment: I tried to wget my domain from server and it was connected successfully and their is already an entry for server IP address mapped to server name on /etc/host file